# Internet Explorer 10 select list thick black border

Tags: css, internet-explorer-10, selectlist

I've just upgraded to IE10 and noticed all my dropdown lists (select lists) when in "dropped down" state have a thick black border on them as below. I cant inspect the element using IE's built in tools so cant fix it! Can anyone assist?

[image]

Comment: That looks more like an auto-complete for an `<input>` than a `<select>`. If it's [IE's own AutoComplete](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/fill-in-website-forms-and-passwords-automatically), listing values you've entered before, this is not a markup element and cannot be styled. If it's a custom auto-complete, such as [with jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), then you'll need to include more details about it (markup, library, etc.).

Comment: My bad - that's exactly what it is - an IE10 autocomplete. How HIDEOUS! Microsoft spend millions on "pretty" and then drop that into their latest browser :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While most of the various components of form elements are stylable in IE10, the popup in select elements can not be styled.